# Explanation for single rainbow that contained colors several times

Tags: atmosphere, atmospheric-optics

I saw a rainbow outside Silverton, CO last week that for a few minutes seemed to show part of the color cycle (red to purple) several times within the same band. This picture is how it looked to my eye. I assume this is some refraction phenomenon of multiple rainbows, or ... ? It was also a double, but that part isn't shown.

[image: showed this banding for a few minutes]

I took another picture a few minutes later of it looking normal (the rainbow brightened, the droplets were bigger, and there was a strong double):

[image]

What is causing this strange banding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It a [supernumerary bow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Supernumerary_rainbows), which results when the droplets that create the rainbow are very small and of nearly uniform size. The droplets need to be small enough so as to make diffraction a significant effect.

Comment: Thank you. Good info on that phenomenon here: http://www.atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/supers.htm